# Unclear constraints in SQL's CREATE TABLE

Tags: sql

In a Coursera course, there is a snippet of code:

[image]

> I don't understand the parts:
>
> - `CONSTRAINT AUTHOR_PK`
> - `(author_id)` (after `PRIMARY KEY`)

> Could you please explain?

**Clarifications**: for `CONSTRAINT AUTHOR_PK`, I don't understand why `CONSTRAINT` is there explicitly but it's not there for the other attributes of the table. I also don't know what `AUTHOR_PK` is used for.

For `(author_id)`, I don't understand its presence. Since `PRIMARY KEY` is written on the same line as `author_id`, isn't it already implicit that `author_id` will be used as the primary key?

I'm very new to SQL. I consulted

- https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_constraints.asp

but could not resolve these issues myself.

Comment: Where did you find that CREATE TABLE? The syntax is very odd and not valid ISO/ANSI SQL. w3*ools is nothing I'd recommend.

Comment: @jarlh It's a video entitled CREATE Table Statement in the Coursera course Databases and SQL for Data Science. Which source would you recommend instead of w3?

Comment: Tough question. To be honest I don't know, since I don't need any beginners tips.

Comment: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/  or http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Main_Page or https://pgexercises.com/ are better than w3fools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of constraints you can create in a `CREATE TABLE` statement. These are column constraints and table constraints.

Column constraints are included in the definition of a single column.

Table constraints are included as separate declarations, not part of a column definition.

This is the same table with the primary key declared as a table constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE Author
(author_id CHAR(2),
 lastname VARCHAR(15) not null,
...,
CONSTRAINT PK_AUTHOR PRIMARY KEY (author_id)
)
```

What you have in your example is a constraint being declared as a column constraint. Normally, column constraints don't have to name which columns they're relevant to since they're part of the column's definition, and indeed in some dialects of SQL, the sample you've shown would be rejected, because it does name the columns explicitly.

`PK_AUTHOR`, in both your sample and mine, is being used to give a specific name to the constraint. This is helpful if you'll later need to remove the constraint. If you don't want to name the constraint, then `CONSTRAINT PK_AUTHOR` may be omitted from either sampe.

Comment: I think the "inline" constraint name is indeed part of the SQL standard (and e.g. supported by [Postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=74d3e423e3c72f96ff42dfb1bb578ba0) and Oracle). However  - as you mentioned - including the column name is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

The `CONSTRAINT` keyword is necessary when you want to provide a specific name for the constraint, in this case `AUTHOR_PK`.  If you don't do this, a name would be auto-generated, and these names are generally not very useful.  All the `NOT NULL` constraints in this example would have auto-generated names.

In my experience, it's standard practice to name all constraints except NOT NULL ones.

I think you are right that `(author_id)` is unnecessary in this example, as it is implied by the fact that the constraint is declared for that column already.  But the syntax allows it.  (I wonder if it would allow specifying a different column in this position - I don't think so but haven't tried it.)

The syntax to specify columns is more useful when you want to declare a multiple-column key. In this case, the `CONSTRAINT` clause would be specified as if it were another column in the table definition:

```
...
country  CHAR(2),
CONSTRAINT one_city_per_country UNIQUE (country,city)
);
```